# How do I complete the equation?

Tags: logarithms

Can someone help me with this equation.

Solve the following logarithmic equation:
$$\log_5 (2x+4)=2$$

this is all I have got. How can I solve this?

Comment: I am assuming you meant $\log_5 (2x+4)$ and not $\log\{5(2x+4)\}$,   $\log_a(b)=y\implies b=a^y$ so here $2x+4=5^2$ so $x=21/2$.

Comment: Why did you use linear algebra tag here?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3976699/edit) your question to incorporate [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hi there! I recommend you look up methods of solving logarithmic equations. As such, it looks like you're just asking us to do your homework for you, which is not what we do here at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do the following trick: if $a=b$ then $5^a=5^b$, and conversely, if $5^a=5^b$ then $a=b$.

Doing the same with your equation, we got:

$$
5^{\log_5 (2x+4)}=5^2
$$

and, as was mentioned above, this equation has the same set of roots since the function $y=5^x$ is continuous and monotonic over $\mathbb{R}$. Hope you can take it from here.

**HINT:** $a^{\log_a b}=b$